# Ajax call doesnt work, no error in the console

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a table subscription with column exported that can have three values:
- success
- failure
- manual

I want to change the value of `exported`when the user clicks somewhere on my page using AJAX.

1. If the element he clicks on has the class `fa-times`, `exported` changes from `failure` to `manual`.
2. If the element he clicks on has the class `verified`, `exported` changes from `manual` to `failure`.

I have tried this without success for 1)(first I get the subscription_id) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-times').on('click', function (event) {
        var subscription_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: " /tournaments/" + "<%=params[:tournament_id]%>"+"/subscriptions/"+ subscription_id,
            dataType: "script",
            data: {
                subscription: {
                    exported: "manual"
                    subscription_id: subscription_id,
                }
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
    });
}),
```

Do you know what's going wrong, I dont get any error in the console.

Comment: can you see any error in browser console.? should there be comma after this `exported: "manual"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for update select box selected element

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
      $('.fa-times').on('click', function(event){
          $('#exported option[value=manual]').attr('selected', true)
      });
      $('.verified').on('click', function(event){
          $('#exported option[value=failure]').attr('selected', true)
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exported">
  <option value="success">success</option>
  <option value="failure">failure</option>
  <option value="manual">manual</option>
</select>
  <div class="fa-times">fa-times</div>
<div class="verified">verified</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but your URL might not taking your call to your correct place. Check the network tab in chrome Inspect Element. Are You getting 200 Status Code? If Yes check you api actually sending data or not? Also you can try with JSON dataType.

Comment: there is nothing in the console and nothing in the network tab

Comment: If there is nothing, probably the on click event not firing the function. Comment your ajax and alert or console something. Then try to fix the ajax.